# Policing "Me Too" Answers Posted by the Asking Member

Tags: discussion, flags, answers

What is the general method for handling users who habitually post useless "me too" answers on their own questions?  See for example [SQL Server -- Loop through each column in every table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915305/sql-server-loop-through-each-column-in-every-table)

I suppose there's nothing really **wrong** with this behavior, but there's certainly nothing gained either. Not to pick on this particular user too much, but he has quite a history of doing so.

Should there be a specific flag type for this? Is the SO community expected to self-police and downvote answers of this type?

Comment: I don't see a "me too" answer

Comment: @VJo: The asking user posted another answer identical to my own, other than formatting and an ordering clause.

Comment: This user has several pointless, vague, or narrow questions with 0 up-vote accepted self-answers.  Several of them look like they should have been deleted questions instead...  Almost all of his answers are to his own questions.

Comment: Ok, I see. LOL what a joke. "Thanks, Yuk -- To expound for the next guy:" as your answer doesn't exists.

Comment: Flag it. Notice though that we do need to be careful about potentially catching legitimate but similar answers - occasionally several people provide the same general response in quick succession. Obviously this case is blatant, but others might not be so.

Comment: @thegrinner - yes, it happens on occasion. See, for example, [Subtle “Me Too” differences](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118834/173448). But Anna Lear fixed it when she learned about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please don't flag stuff like this as "Not an Answer".  That post **is an answer**.  He accepted (and in all likelihood upvoted) your answer before posting the actual code he ended up using.  He even acknowledged your answer as a part of his own answer.  He's not trying anything tricky here, so there's nothing wrong with that post.

Comment: True, it *is* an answer and I agree it was good of the OP to not select his own as **the** answer. However, I don't see what value it has? Not trying to argue with you - just looking for clarification - and thanks for your input.

Comment: @Yuck: The value is in posting what is (presumably) the exact code that was tested and works.  I don't think someone should be punished for doing that.  Even if he only reformatted it for readability, it's not *not* an answer.  (If it were a copy/paste of your answer, naturally that would be flaggable.)

Comment: Fair enough, +1

Answer (score 5):

You can always flag these as "Not an answer". They are usualy considered as noise.

Answer (score 4):

There's no specific flag for that, but there's always the "not an answer" flag, which is what I always choose, because that's the simple truth of it - the so-called answer is really not an answer, and would be better off as a comment, or gone.