# What can I do when an answer to my problem is found in comments under a similar, but not quite the same question?

Tags: discussion

So: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074040/maven-failing-to-download-jar-dependencies/8829274#8829274) which was similar enough to my own problems that I tried the listed answers.

However, the "real" answer (the one that helped me) was actually hidden down in the comments to the "accepted" answer. I don't have enough privileges (yet?) to vote the answer up or down or even to comment on the answer (which I would have preferred). So I thought I would give the "real" answer a bit more weight by answering "Me too" (essentially).

My answer was deleted, but I wonder: shouldn't there be some way to help a new user like me underline an answer that was more helpful than the supposed answer to a question?

Comment: 1) Participate in acceptable ways. 2) Accrue at least 15 points of reputation (2 upvotes on an answer, 3 on a question), 3) ??? 4) Return and cast your vote.

Comment: The vote up privilege only requires 15 reputation, which is pretty easy to get. Just ask or answer a couple of questions first.

Comment: ... or post answers to questions.

Comment: Thanks for participating intelligently and trying to help out.  Looks like you have enough rep to comment and upvote now :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ahh, that's my bad. Sorry.

Your answer got flagged as "not an answer" and with the way it was written, I'd assumed that it was a repeat of another answer. I've restored your answer and edited it to make it clear that it's a solution. This should prevent future flags on it.

In general, it's best to either explicitly reference another solution or to just make your answer stand on its own. Most people won't check every comment on the page and comments can also be removed pretty easily, so I don't recommend relying on them for reference.

Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: No problem. I'm still learning how this community works and I'm glad my answer was taken in consideration after all. Thanks!